# Kotlin: Reading file from external storage (Android 11)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

**Objective:** Allow user to select a file (file picker) and copy that file to the internal storage.

**Problem:** I can't read the file that the user has selected.

**Error:** `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:17022: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

The below will execute after user selects a file from the external storage (Eg. from the Download folder)

```
val fileActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->

        if(result.resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data = result.data
            val uri = data?.data!!
            val file = File(uri.path!!)
            val readBytes = file.inputStream().readBytes()
        }
    }
)
```

I've seen plenty of solutions but they don't seem to work.

**Solution:**

I've used the solution that was provided by blackapps and it works without any issue.

Here's what I've changed to:

```
val fileActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->

        if(result.resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data = result.data
            val uri = data?.data!!
            val readBytes = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.readBytes()
            val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(readBytes)

            //I wanted to store the file in the database directory, replace with whatever path you need
            val path = this.getDatabasePath("database_name").canonicalPath.dropLast(7)
            val file = File(path, "test")
                
                inputStream.use { input->
                    file.outputStream().use { output->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: `/document/msf:17022` That is no file system path which you could easily check with File.exists() and File.canRead(). And one cannot use the File class for an Uri.

Comment: getContentResolver().openInputStream(result.data)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help. You should put that as an answer.